# How to copy a range, ignoring rows where the value in column 2 is blank

Tags: excel, vba

I'm using a button macro to copy a range, it's super simple:

```
Worksheets("SNOW").Range("C6:D18").Copy
```

Now, how would I modify this to say "Copy this range, but if the value in column D is blank, skip that row completely in the copy process"? Dealing with text, not numbers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use `Union` to create a range that contains only your select rows (if the value in column D is not blank):

```
Sub Test()

Dim rng As Range, i As Long

For i = 6 To 18
    If Range("D" & i).Value <> "" Then
        If rng Is Nothing Then
            Set rng = Range("C" & i & ":D" & i)
        Else
            Set rng = Application.Union(rng, Range("C" & i & ":D" & i))
        End If
    End If
Next i

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    rng.Copy
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Very neat way to copy disjoint sets of cells *(+1)*

Comment: So this does help, in a way. When it reaches the first row where D is blank, it stops the copy of all rows. However, if row 1 has data and row 2 is blank and row 3 has data again, it is copying all three rows whereas I'd like it to only copy rows 1 and 3 because they contain data in the second column

Comment: @KeithR That shouldn't be how it's working - what this does is checks each cell in column D from rows 6 to 18 - if that cell has text, it's added to our  variable `rng`. At the end, `rng` is added to the clipboard.

Comment: I recognize that it shouldn't be but it is.

Answer (score 1):

You could filter and copy the filtered data:

```
Sub Copy_Filtered()

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Snow")
        If .FilterMode Then
            .ShowAllData
        End If

        With .Range("A6:D18")
            .AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="<>"
            .Copy 'Destination:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Blizzard").Range("A1")
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

**NB:**  Uncomment the Destination to paste the range to the Blizzard sheet.

Comment: This is definitely the fastest method. +1

Answer (score 0):

You can copy each area separately.

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, r As Range, rCpy As Range
    Dim rDest As Range

Set ws = Worksheets("SNOW")
With ws
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(6, 4), .Cells(18, 4)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)
    Set rDest = .Cells(6, 10)

    For Each rCpy In r.Areas
        Set rCpy = rCpy.Offset(columnoffset:=-1).Resize(columnsize:=2)
        rCpy.Copy rDest
        Set rDest = rDest.Offset(rCpy.Rows.Count)
    Next rCpy
End With

End Sub
```

Another method, which will work no matter what the contents of the source data:

```
Set ws = Worksheets("SNOW")
With ws
    .Rows.Hidden = False
    Set rDest = .Cells(1, 6)
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(6, 4), .Cells(18, 4)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
    r.EntireRow.Hidden = True
    Set r = .Range(.Cells(6, 3), .Cells(18, 4)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    .Rows.Hidden = False
    r.Copy rDest
End With
```